# How to pause and resume execution of a html page on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a web page that resembles a video. So I need to pause the web page at a point when the user presses the button and continue from that point itself.

Comment: Cool, so what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried setTimeout but I am not getting what I want. I want an effect which we get when we pause a video. I want this effect in my html

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "pause" execution of HTML at will. You can control when and how different parts of your website [gets revealed](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp) using javascript by showing items(initially hidden using css) either via actions (button clicks for ex) by user or using a timer. See [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```js
function removeClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList)
    el.classList.remove(className);
  else {
    var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)');
    el.className = el.className.replace(reg, ' ');
  }
}

function revealDivInTime(id, time) {
  var div = document.getElementById(id);
  if (div) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      removeClass(div, "hidden");
    }, time);
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("start").onclick = function() {
    revealDivInTime("one", 1000);
    revealDivInTime("two", 5000);
    revealDivInTime("three", 10000);
  }
  document.getElementById("end").onclick = function() {
    revealDivInTime("four", 0);
    revealDivInTime("five", 3000);
    revealDivInTime("three", 10000);
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Click to start story: <button id="start">click me</button>
</div>
<div id="one" class="hidden">
  <p>First Part of story revealed after 1 second</p>
</div>
<div id="two" class="hidden">
  <p>Second Part of story revealed after 5 seconds</p>
</div>
<div id="three" class="hidden">
  <p>Third Part of story revealed after 10 seconds</p>
  <p> Click this button to finish Story: <button id="end">Finish</button>
</div>
<div id="four" class="hidden">
  <p>This get's revealed only after user clicks on button in story part 3. Story will end in 3 seconds</p>
</div>
<div id="five" class="hidden">
  <p>Story finished</p>
</div>
```

Example of pausing and playing reveals:

```js
var currentScene = 0,
  looper, sceneCount = 10,
  isPlaying = false;

function removeClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList)
    el.classList.remove(className);
  else {
    var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)');
    el.className = el.className.replace(reg, ' ');
  }
}

function nextScene() {
  currentScene++;
  if (currentScene > sceneCount) {
    clearInterval(looper);
    isPlaying = false;
    return;
  }
  removeClass(document.getElementById("s"+currentScene),"hidden");
}

function play() {
  if (isPlaying) {
    return;
  }
  isPlaying = true;
  looper = setInterval(nextScene, 2000);
}

function pause() {
  if (!isPlaying) {
    return;
  }
  isPlaying = false;
  clearInterval(looper);
}

document.getElementById("play").onclick=function(){play();};
document.getElementById("pause").onclick=function(){pause();};
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="play">Play</button><button id="pause">Pause</button>
<div id="s1" class="hidden">
  Scene 1
</div>
<div id="s2" class="hidden">
  Scene 2
</div>
<div id="s3" class="hidden">
  Scene 3
</div>
<div id="s4" class="hidden">
  Scene 4
</div>
<div id="s5" class="hidden">
  Scene 5
</div>
<div id="s6" class="hidden">
  Scene 6
</div>
<div id="s7" class="hidden">
  Scene 7
</div>
<div id="s8" class="hidden">
  Scene 8
</div>
<div id="s9" class="hidden">
  Scene 9
</div>
<div id="s10" class="hidden">
  Scene 10. Story Over. Click reload and click play to start again.
</div>
```

Comment: how can I pause  a part of my code when i click stop button and resume from that point only when i click the play button

Comment: You can achieve the pause/play effect by using setInterval and removeInterval. Keep variables to track current scene and use setInterval (and store reference to later remove it) to periodically reveal scenes (while keeping the currentScene variable updated to track which scene the user saw last). When user presses pause, remove the interval using removeInterval on the stored reference you got when used setInterval (this will "pause"). When user resumes, call setInterval again to continue periodically revealing scenes based on state of the variable which tracks the last seen scene.

Comment: I am not able to understand this method. Can you show a little example of it?

Comment: Have added a basic example for your reference

Comment: correction: It is not removeInterval it is `clearInterval`